# How to remove the squares through the legend markers in ListPlot?

Tags: legending

I am drawing a plot with some legends. It seems the legend markers will always have squares in each line. My question is, is it possible to get rid of those squares through the legend markers? is there another way to do it?

````
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
A = ( {
    {-5, 0},
    {-4, 1},
    {-3, 1},
    {-2, 0}
   } );

X = ListLinePlot[A, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005], AbsoluteDashing[5]}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(~\)], \(11\
\)]\)= (-4,-3,1,1)"}, 
     LegendMarkers -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005], AbsoluteDashing[5]}], 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];

Show[X, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Negative Fuzzy Solution \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(~\)]\)", 
 PlotRange -> All]```
````

Comment: Remove `LegendMarkers`, you also need `FrameLabel` not `AxesLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems working:

```
A = ({{-5, 0}, {-4, 1}, {-3, 1}, {-2, 0}});
X = ListLinePlot[A, PlotTheme -> "Scientific",  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005], AbsoluteDashing[5]}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
    LineLegend[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(~\)], \(11\)]\)= (-4,-3,1,1)"}, Joined -> False, 
     LegendMarkers ->   Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[0.1], Line[{{-4, 0}, {4, 0}}]}], 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];

Show[X, PlotLabel -> "Negative Fuzzy Solution \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(X\), \(~\)]\)", PlotRange -> All]
```